# I can't reinstall or update Electron package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\nodejs projects\New>npm update electron

> electron@1.8.1 postinstall D:\nodejs projects\New\node_modules\electron
>   node install.js

I have this error when I start the project:

Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again

Comment: I have this error when i start the project:

Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again

Comment: This is all what you see in the console ?

Comment: Have you tried to delete and npm install again ?

Comment: yes i uninstall  npm and install it

Comment: try removing electron and adding it again.  run 'npm uninstall electron' and 'npm install electron'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment from @illiteratewriter did the trick:

Remove electron and add it again using the following commands:

```
npm uninstall electron
npm install electron
```

Comment: That's what it said to do--why wasn't that the first thing you did?